# Projecting line through the scene

Tags: phaser-framework

I need to find the nearest intersection of a given line with the objects (or physical bodies) on the scene.
Is there an easy way in Phaser 3 to do it? Or do I need to find intersection points with individual objects?

Comment: It's just some mathematical calculations no ? Then if the sprite is somewhere why don't you just take its coordinates ?

Comment: There could be a lot of sprites and other objects with large physical bodies on the scene. I need to know which one (if any) is intersected and where.

Comment: Any attempt in jsfiddle or codepen ?

Comment: @nazimboudeffa You mean, if I tried to search there? Yes, I did. I don't think there is an easy way. Now trying the hard one.

Comment: I wonder to see how you first try choose jsfiddle or codepen and let me know, please

Comment: @nazimboudeffa Problem solved, but I don't have an account on these servers yet, so no promises to extract the code there. Generally speaking, I used (1) `Phaser.Geom.Intersects.LineToLine` against the individual lines of the world-bounding polygon, and (2) `Phaser.Geom.Intersects.GetLineToCircle` against the circular custom 'bodies' of the world objects.

Comment: Nice to see it fixed o/ ;)